# How can I receive send and recieve multiple data with an implicit intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, implicit

I am sending an implicit intent from one activity to another and I want to send some String variables. I'm doing this as an implicit intent as I wish to use activity B in multiple projects, it's part of a library project.

I have got the intent working just fine but the extra data is not being read in at activity B.

Here's my code in Activity A to create the intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShareResultsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EMAIL_SUBJECT, "Results");//String
    intent.putExtra(RESULTS_SAVENAME, saveName);//String
    intent.putExtra(RESULTS_BODY, body);//String
    intent.putExtra(WITH_SAVE_BUTTON, withSaveButton);//Boolean
    startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity B:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Boolean withSaveButton = true;

    if(extras != null){
        emailSubject = extras.getString("EMAIL_SUBJECT");
        resultsSaveName = extras.getString("RESULTS_SAVENAME");
        resultsBody = extras.getString("RESULTS_BODY");
        withSaveButton = extras.getBoolean("WITH_SAVE_BUTTON", true);
    }
```

This doesn't work and the String variables are null.

I have also tried to do this in the way an explicit intent recieves the data:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    emailSubject = intent.getStringExtra("EMAIL_SUBJECT");
    resultsSaveName = intent.getStringExtra("RESULTS_SAVENAME");
    resultsBody = intent.getStringExtra("RESULTS_BODY");
    Boolean withSaveButton = intent.getBooleanExtra("WITH_SAVE_BUTTON", true);
```

But this doesn't work either.

The only way I can get it to work is if I reference the sending Activity in getStringExtra but I can't do this as it's supposed to be a library class.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: what is the `EMAIL_SUBJECT ` variable's value?

Comment: I'm an idiot, my Activity B should be looking for that same value. If you give me an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your code like this:

```
final static String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "email_subject";
//  RESULTS_SAVENAME and others are the same style.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShareResultsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EMAIL_SUBJECT, "Results");//String
startActivity(intent);
```

then in your another activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
emailSubject = intent.getStringExtra("email_subject");
// or this
// emailSubject = intent.getStringExtra(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the key , it should be same in both the activities. I clearly see a difference in naming convention of the key name in both the activities.If key name is same, no way it data should not pass.